# Platform Game: screen movement methods not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Here is my flash game without a vcam or any other screen movement methods:
http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1389129611
I used the hitTestPoint method to handle my collisions. However, when I tried adding a vcam this was the result:
http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1389130109
Is that strange or what? The code I used for the vcam was:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update_vcam);
function update_vcam(e:Event){
    vcam.x=char.x;
    vcam.y=char.y;
}
```

The vcam's demensions are exactly the same as the stage(and are also perfectly aligned to the stage). I used "Jazza's" virtual camera. I've also tried many other vcams, but each one proves to be as messed up. I used to use vcams all the time back in the as2 days, and they always worked. This is not the only method I've tried. I also tried moving the ground instead of the character. Here's the result:
http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1389130683
I have absolutely no idea what's going on. Any ideas?

Drake Swartzy

Comment: are yo sure char.x and char.y change? put a trace in update_cam.

Comment: Yes @Discipol, unfortunately the characters x and y values do change. That's a good thought though, that's what I thought too.

Comment: I just tried tracing the x values of the vcam for each frame. At first I thought there might be a pattern. I tried subtracting the frame vcam x values, but the x values seem to be completely random, other than the fact that the values decrease and repeat themselves twice.

Comment: Perhaps someone knows of a better screen movement method than the two I tried? I've already searched through the internet a dozen times but I couldn't find anything on this issue. I'd also be willing to post my code if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what vcam is, but setting up a camera is actually really simple. All you need to do is have all of your game objects in a container, and offset that container based on the 'camera' position.

For example, you have all of your game objects in a `Sprite` named `world`. Within that sprite you have another object called `char`. What you need to do from here is set the `x` and `y` of the `world` to the negative position of the `char`, plus half of the screen size to center the `char`:

```
// A 'Camera' is really just a Point within the world we want to center on
// the screen.
var camera:Point = new Point();

// Set the camera coordinates to the char coordinates.
camera.x = char.x;
camera.y = char.y;

// Adjust the world position on the screen based on the camera position.
world.x = -camera.x + (stage.stageWidth / 2);
world.y = -camera.y + (stage.stageHeight / 2);
```

This could be made into a simple camera type class like so:

```
public class Camera2D
{

    private var _position:Point;
    private var _world:Sprite;
    private var _stage:Stage;


    public function Camera2D(world:Sprite, stage:Stage)
    {
        _position = new Point();
        _world = world;
        _stage = stage;
    }


    public function set x(value:Number):void
    {
        _position.x = value;
        _world.x = -_position.x + (_stage.stageWidth / 2);
    }


    public function set y(value:Number):void
    {
        _position.y = value;
        _world.y = -_position.y + (_stage.stageHeight / 2);
    }


    public function get x():Number{ return _position.x; }
    public function get y():Number{ return _position.y; }

}
```

And implemented like:

```
var camera:Camera2D = new Camera2D(world, stage);
camera.x = char.x;
camera.y = char.y;
```

Comment: Ah you were faster, and explain the things way better. :P

Comment: Thankyou Marty Wallace and Zhafur for your fast responses! I'll try this method out (by the way, a vcam is a virtual camera used especially by animators to easily move the stage view without having to move each individual item)

Comment: @Marty how would you add declare and initiate a sprite, then how would you add everything to the sprite?

Comment: @Moynul That is fundamental usage of AS3 and far too broad for me to answer for you.

Comment: @Marty hey, sorry for being naive. I followed your answer, the hero is in the sprite, level is in the sprite. 

However, the code kinda disrupts the collision. 

I'm not sure why.

Would appreciate it if you can give me a solution.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you any solution for this problem, but can suggest a better solution. Instead of using a "virtual camera", write your own camera class, but doesn't even need to be a class, can be function aswell if you don't want to obfuscate it.

Cameras are not actually cameras but a point of view, so instead moving that camera, you could just put everything into a container, let's say a gameContainer sprite, and move that sprite like this:

```
gameContainer.x = -char.x + (stage.stageWidth / 2);
gameContainer.y = -char.y + (stage.stageHeight / 2);
```

This is a way better approach, like in other games, the camera isn't really moving, we move the "world" around the player. I'd like to also suggest writing classes and use AS3.0 as an Object Oriented language. Object oriented programming gives the programmers huge advantages, like better view of the code, seperated classes, easier to read aswell. Try it, not that hard.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Zhafur, up until now I've been kind of avoiding OOP, partly because I'm too lazy :) and because it seems inconvenient. However, I've noticed how many people use it. Now that you mention it, I think I'll give it a go